# How to call specific numpy from two versions

Tags: python, numpy, path

While running a script, I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py:110: UserWarning: Numpy 1.8.2 or above is recommended for this version of scipy (detected version 1.7.1)
  UserWarning)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hicCorrectMatrix", line 4, in <module>
    from hicexplorer.hicCorrectMatrix import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hicexplorer/hicCorrectMatrix.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I am running hicCorrectMatrix from hicexplorer.

The program was installed as:

```
/opt/miniconda2/bin/conda install hicexplorer -c bioconda -c conda-forge
```

It seems, it's a path related problem.

```
I have two versions of numpy.
python2 -c 'import numpy; print (numpy.version.version)'
1.7.1
python3 -c 'import numpy; print (numpy.version.version)'
1.16.2
```

Somehow the program is looking for numpy version 1.7.1 instead of 1.16.2.

```
whereis numpy
numpy: /usr/include/numpy
```

However, if I wish to upgrade the numpy, I end up as.

```
    pip install numpy --upgrade
    Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.16.2)
    pip3 install numpy --upgrade
    Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.16.2)

/opt/miniconda2/bin/conda install -c conda-forge numpy
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Please let me know how to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using conda, create a new environment that has the required version of numpy.

Comment: Did you try specifying python version while running conda by supplying `python=2.7` as command line argument

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I had to set the PYTHONPATH variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH="/opt/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"
```